# Angular Intellisense in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I know you get intellisense in Visual Studio if you set up a Visual Studio Angular project.

But is there any way to get intellisense when you set up a new Angular project created using "ng new" with angular-cli and then choose open folder from Visual Studio 2019?

Also is there a way to get intellisense for Bootstrap 4 when you open the angular folder project in this fashion?

Comment: I just created a project with "ng new" and opened it in VS2019. I opened it as a folder from the start screen and I also closed that and opened it by right-clicking an empty solution and choosing "Add -> Existing Web Site". In both cases I had intellisense for Angular constructs. What version of VS and .Net Core are you using?

Comment: Not sure about VS2019, but if I create a new Angular project using ng new, and open folder in VS2017, the intellisense works well.

Comment: Hi Sam, any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi Sam, I dd the same and found that Angular intellisense was OK, but Bootstrap intellisense in component HTML files wasn't working. Did you resolve this?

Comment: No I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue with Visual Studio 2019, on a VS solution started as a Node.Js project and after some weeks an Angular application has been added to the same project in the VS solution. Results : there is no Intellisense for my Angular code.

My temporary solution is to open with VS Code the folder where is my angular source code.

@+
rv.

Answer (score 0):

1. For using Angular IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2019, you should install the **Angular Language Service** extension which is available in [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.AngularLanguageService&ssr=false#review-details).

It would be noticeable that this extension is compatible with **Visual Studio 2019  V16.5.0** or up.

For more information follow [This link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/angular-language-service-for-visual-studio/).

2. For using **Bootstrap IntelliSense** in Visual Studio 2019 read [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956718/is-there-a-way-to-get-intellisense-for-bootstrap-and-fontawsome-in-angular-proje/68456319#68456319)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found to work is just create a solution:
From the dotnet CLI

> Dotnet new sln -n MySolution

Then open the solution in Visual Studio and right click the solution and select Add New Website.
You get a new dialogue where you can pick a site from IIS, FTP or a folder.
Pick folder and navigate to the folder you ran ng new in.

Then I get all the intellisense in the world for Angular, bootstrap and everything else.

Something like this. I'm writing from memory I haven't actually been in there for a while.