# Visual studio extensions for intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

my question isn't code related but rather visual studio related.

Currently I begin to program more with vue and angular.
So I'd like to have extension which gives me some intellisense on the code.
In vs 2019 and 2017 I think I had web essentials for that, hiowever that doesn't seem to be updated to vs 2022.

Yes vs code is better for front end, but I'm rather a backend developer and currently when I have some wbeb api's I'd like my angular in the same project when i'm working in vvisual studio.

My current extensions in vs 2022:

- better razor css intellisense
- htlp snippet pack
- javascript snippet pack
- vue.js code snippets
- asp.net core spa with vue js
- markdown editor v2
- reattach
- resharper

Does somebody know of extensions that can give intellisense on typescript and/or bootstrap / css?

Any other extension recommendations are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get intellisense on typescript and/or bootstrap/css. We can see from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) that “ By default, Visual Studio 2022 provides language support for JavaScript and TypeScript files to power IntelliSense without any specific project configuration.”

Here are some links about intellisense for bootstrap/css, hope it helps.( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58991272/17296043) and [2](https://irsali.github.io/others/2017/10/06/Visual-Studio-Ensuring-Intellisense.html) )

If you need some extensions you can search in [this page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vs)

Comment: the second was more usefull, i think since it said to add the unminified version, bootstrap is auto installed in the template of a webproject, but I think it uses the cdn, I'll check out if I have intellisense if I manually add the bootstrap file rather then the cdn